# Error in my proof?

Tags: real-analysis

What is wrong in this proof. It seems correct to me but still doesn't make proper sense.

$$\sqrt{\cdots\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{5}}}}=5^{1/\infty}=5^0=1$$

EDIT

So does this mean that

$5^{1/\infty} = 1$

$(5^{1/\infty})^\infty = 1^\infty$

But according to me, $1^\infty$ is indeterminate.

Comment: What those periods in the first square root mean??

Comment: It means square rooting infinitely

Comment: $1/\infty$ is most definitely not something you can use in anything resembling a mathematical proof...

Comment: Er...square root **of what** ?

Comment: Before asking for a correct proof, you may need to ask for a correct formalisation of the problem.

Comment: Let $a=\sqrt{...\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{5}}}}$, then $a(a-1)=0$, so $a=0$ or $a=1$, thus this "quantity" does not exist?? What? am I hallucinating? What prevents $a$ from being zero?

Comment: (Apart from the fact that infinite expressions are IMO delirious in general unless of a special kind for which meaning is given to them in special way, this one is particularly insidious:) Since there is both an innermost and an outermost square root sign (both visible), there is a serious question about what the dots mean if they suggest infinite repetition (and if it is finite we clearly need to know how many). Are they indexed, from the inside outwards by $\omega+1$ (so after taking the limit take one more root), or some other cardinal, or maybe they are not well-ordered in the first place?

Comment: The fundamental error is in using $\infty$ as a number.

Comment: You don't have any error except a lack of rigor; you're right that as you take more roots of 5 the result approaches 1.

Comment: Treating $\frac{1}{\infty}$ as a number, or taking the $\infty$th power of both sides, is not something that math approves of. Or allows, even.

Comment: As for your last observation, note that $(5^{\frac{1}{\infty}})^\infty$ is indeterminate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you mean this:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}5^{1/2^n}=1$$

Comment: Perhaps he did, yet that weird use of periods in that root and then the weirder use of infinity makes this doubtful.

Comment: @Timbuc both the dots and reciprocal of infinity make sense and *may* be properly formalized as several answers did instead of making fun for not expressing the obvious meaning in the way that is thought proper

Comment: @Mirko What's the meaning of those periods *at the beginning of the square root* ? Can you guess? I can't. Also, I can't guess who's making fun of whom or what for who knows what.

Comment: @Timbuc they are not at the beginning they are at the end. Look from the inside to the outside. Read from right to left as necessary (and as it is usually done for function composition). How did all those people that posted answers interpreted the question in a similar way?

Comment: @Mirko Why would anyone read from right to left? That is a mathematical expression and as such, and unless otherwise stated, it must be read from left to right, and thus it begins with periods in the square root. What other people understood is something I can't answer.

Comment: @Timbuc because *everyone* reads function composition from right to left, you know very well. But you are right.

Comment: @Mirko I beg to difer greatly. What is closer to the truth, perhaps, is that *in order to find out what the composition is* many people usually read the comoposition from right to left. That could be true.

Answer (score 12):

What seems incorrect is because the language seems informal. Formally, one would write 
$$
x_0=5, \quad x_n = \sqrt{x_{n-1}}
$$
to describe the iterations of the square roots. One computes easily that 
$$
x_n = x_0^{1/{2^n}}
$$
and since $x_0^{1/n} \to 1$ for all $x_0 > 0$, so does $x_n$. (You can prove this by showing that the logarithm of the sequence goes to $0$ ; this is trivial.)

Hope that helps,

Comment: Apparently the OP meant infinite square roots *at the beginning*, otherwise his use of infinity is even more odd.

Comment: What do you mean "at the beginning", that makes no sense to me

Comment: @Pa Neither to me, yet how else can one explain the infinity in the OP's post? Even more interesting, that'd be infinite square roots... *of what* ?

Comment: @Timbuc I appreciate your discussion. I wonder if it would have made any difference if the dots were placed more to the right or "at the end". We may start a discussion about use of dots in math and when it is proper. But I think it was said enough already, thank you.

Comment: @Mirko If the OP has used $\;n\;$ **anywhere, somewhere** , maybe I, and perhaps others, could have deduced easily that he meant the iteration of the square roots $\;n\;$ times ...but he didn't. In fact, from first sight, I even though that he would be working with some $\;p$-adic ring or field.

Comment: I would write more formally what the OP, apparently, meant: $$a_1=\sqrt5\;,\;\;a_2=\sqrt{\sqrt5}\,,\ldots,a_n=\overbrace{\sqrt{\sqrt{\ldots \sqrt5}}}^{n\;\text{square roots}}$$ and then **also** use somehow $\;n\;$ in my expression for limit. That way one could hardly get misled by the expression.

Comment: @Timbuc Now I get it, you have seen too much, that is why it looked ambiguous :) I am blissfully ignorant about the possible (mis)use of dots in the context of $p$-adics. BTW in your previous comment you guessed the intended meaning of the question. Did you do this on your own (and if so, how)? Or did you just copied what the others did?

Comment: @Mirko Jeje...don't worry about that: it will come in time (or not...). It is just a rather useful, in certain aspects, way of writing a $\;p$-adic number in a way ressembling the infinite expression of real numbers with decimal expansion...bit in the $\;p$-adic case it *end to the right*, with the periods on the left, unlike the real, and usual, case.

Comment: @Timbuc : What else could he have meant? I don't see any other plausible option.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva I already wrote elsewhere: infinite square roots, which means god knows what, but which seemed to be so because of the OP's use of that infinite sign. "Plausible" is the key word here: it really didn't look like a plausible/logical/makes-sense question, and this is reflected by several comments/answers here. Read in particular Mark's comment below the question.

Comment: @Timbuc : No offense, but in my opinion it is just arrogant to tell the OP is not being clear when he probably doesn't know how to formulate his question with a 100% clear mathematical precision. It is more user-friendly to guess his answer, make oneself clear, and then if by any chance the OP did not mean what we guessed, discuss with him and figure out what the actual question was. I understand your mathematical worries, but we're not here to pass an exam and be 100% right all the time but rather to help people and learn all together!

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva I strongly disagree with you. Imo, mathematics students must be well aware of the fact that they *must* try to be as precise and clear as possible, since sometimes even little imprecisions can lead to huge misunderstandings/mistakes. In this case I honestly didn't know what the OP meant, and reading what he wrote ($\;5^{1/\infty}$) made it even more confusing as I was *sure* he meant infinite square roots *at the beginning* ...and I'm not the only one who seems to have thougt that way. I think it truly is arrogant to believe students being corrected are going to be offended.

Comment: @Timbuc : I'm not going against that! I'm saying that in the helping process, instead of just saying "what are you saying?" using bold letters and stuff, it might be nicer to suggest what the OP might mean and start a discussion with him rather than simply tell the OP that he is confused. If he wasn't, he wouldn't have asked a question in the first place.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva Perhaps I missed something, but I can't remember now when did I write the OP in bold letter and etc. "what are you saying?" BTW, the OP's first comment, below mine,  explicitly says "it means square rooting infinitely"...I think both he and I, and perhaps others, already learned a good deal of all these discussions, and maybe next time he'll be more careful with the way he writes down things in mathematics...just as many, perhaps most, of us learned in the past.

Comment: @Timbuc : I meant the two separately, about the bold. To prevent looking arrogant I usually reserve the use of bold only to warn a reader that a detail of my comment is very important to read. If I just want to attract attention on some point, I usually use italic ; it looks less aggressive but still attracts attention, whereas bold tends to mean "danger".

 Of course many of us learned from this. Have fun on the website.

Answer (score 3):

Let $x=\sqrt{\sqrt{...\sqrt{5}}}$.
$$x^2 = \sqrt{\sqrt{...\sqrt{5}}} = x$$
$$x = 0 \,  or \, 1 $$

Verify:$$\sqrt{5}=2.24$$
$$\sqrt{\sqrt{5}}=1.50$$
$$...$$
From the pattern we can see $x$ tends to $1$, so $x = 0$ is rejected.

Comment: You have a good idea here. Could you explain it more clearly?

Comment: I understand that: I mean you should add your clarification to your answer. The other unclear part is your parenthetical comment. That should be expanded after you state "$x=0$ or $x=1$". The terseness seems confusing to me. --Why did you delete your comment? The material was good, I simply recommend that you put that comment into your main answer.

Comment: This is a good way to derive possible values for $x$, but it is not in itself a proof that any of the values actually work.  (Try solving $x^{x^{x^{\dots}}}=2$ and $x^{x^{x^{\dots}}}=4$ [what? the same value for $x$ in each?].)

Comment: @KyleMiller Nice counterexample. Maybe using limit identities is enough to find x, just like other answers.

Answer (score 1):

$\sqrt{...\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{5}}}}=\lim x_n$, where $x_n=5^{(1/2^n)} (n\in\mathbb{N})$

Comment: No, at best it denotes the square root of that limit.

Comment: @Marc but square root of $1$ is $1$ :)

Answer (score 1):

$$n=\sqrt{...\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{5}}}}$$

Since there's an infinite cascade of roots, we can add 1 (or as many as we want):

$$n=\sqrt{...\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{5}}}}}$$

Replacing by the $n$ from the first equation:

$$n=\sqrt{n}$$

or

$$n^2=n$$

Since square roots of a number greater than 1 never can become less than 1, we can discard the solution $n=0$, so we can divide both sides by n, and

$$n=1$$

Comment: That argumentation only works if you already know that the sequence converges. Otherwise you'll find that $1+2+4+8+\ldots=-1$ because it obviously fulfils the equation $2x+1=x$, and $-1$ is the only solution to that equation.

Comment: @celtschk: If we agree that square roots are  *positive* , the fact that extraction of a  square root for a number bigger than 1 yields a smaller number, assures we are  safer grounds: a monotonically decreasing sequence of positive numbers.

Comment: @PVanchinathan: Yes, that's a simple proof that the sequence converges. But the answer is missing such a proof.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}x^{1/2^n}=1$$ because the exponent approaches zero

Comment: The exponent approaching zero is not sufficient. Think of $0^0$.

Comment: @stevenvh The base is fixed! Your comment doesn't apply.

Comment: @egreg - I know it doesn't, but *saying* it does not apply doesn't count. For a rigorous proof he has to *show* it, otherwise his proof is incomplete, as you no doubt know.

Comment: @stevenvh Actually in a lot of contexts/mathematics,  $0^0=1$ is perfectly fine :).  (Yes, it's a point of contention)

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n^{y_n}=(\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n)^{\lim_{n\to \infty}y_n}$

Comment: Except when it is an indeterminate form.

Comment: This is false, otherwise $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n=\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\,1/n\right)\right)^{\lim n}=1^{\lim n}=\ldots ??$$

Comment: Does lim n exist? @Timbuc

Comment: @Paul Yes: it is $\;\infty\;$ .... not to mention that you didn't mention anything about existence.

Answer (score 0):

Using $1/\infty$ doesn't make sense, as already stated, because ∞ is not a number, it is a concept. I believe this is the closest thing to what you're really asking.

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}5^{1/n}=1$$

This is true. n never actually reaches infinity, but we find what happens as it gets closer and closer. And it does, indeed, approach 1.

This is because as n gets larger and larger, 1/n gets smaller and smaller. It is known as infinitesimal, essentially zero. It's a little more complicated than just zero (if you're interested, learn calculus, specifically limits and infinitesimals) but for the purposes of this, it's as good as zero. And because $5^{0}=1$, the limit shown above is equal to 1.

Edit: I'd also like to add that using infinity as a number is a bad idea.

$$1+\infty = \infty$$
$$2+\infty = \infty$$
$$1+\infty = 2+\infty$$
$$1 = 2$$